# External display not working with MacBook in clamshell mode (laptop lid closed)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, closed-clamshell

I have seen the previous posts about this and have followed them but it didn't work. Particularly [this seemed really promising until it didn't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307904/external-monitor-not-working-when-in-closed-clamshell-mode) :)

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro that I use with an external monitor till last week. All of a sudden the monitor doesn't work and instead gives me a "Invalid input error" message. It still works when the laptop lid is open though. I was using 10.15.3 when I saw the error, then updated to 10.15.4 and still doesn't work. Anyone else seeing this error? Its driving me nuts.

I also tried a MacBook Air and it works fine. So at least I know the display is working fine and the issue is with the MacBook Pro.

Comment: What gives you the "Invalid Input Error?"  The monitor or the Mac?  If the monitor, it sounds like your GPU died.  It's time to take it in for service.

Comment: The monitor gives me that error. GPU dying makes perfect sense! Is there a way to check this?

Comment: I used the power on HW test (holding down the D button during boot) and it says it didn't find any issues.

Comment: The diagnostics on later model Macs aren’t as robust as earlier models.  Either way, the symptoms tell us what we need to know: no signal is coming from the logic board to the external monitor.